# Jenkins - GitHub Push - How retrieve branch name

Tags: git, jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline

I have a private Github repository and I receive the push events for all my branches into my pipeline of Jenkins 2.89.4.

I cannot have a multibranch project, I need to process all builds with the same pipeline for push, and a different pipeline for pull requests.

It works fine for pull requests with the pull request builder. For  push into my second pipeline, I can't seem to find the branch name.

When I received the push in a maven project instead, I could retrieve the branch name with GIT_BRANCH environment variable.

Now, with pipeline, there is no environment variable containing the branch name. I listed them with :
`echo bat(returnStdout: true, script: 'set')`

Is there a way I can access the GitHup push data or retrieve the branch name ?

Or do I go back to SCM polling ?

---

A patch I developed for the time being, is to read the polling log to extract the branch name. Works for scm polling and github triggering. But I was hoping for an Api.

Comment: have you tried env.BRANCH_NAME ?

Comment: Branch_name is not in the list, and is filled by multi branch project. My project is a simple pipeline project.